# Accessing nested elements's properties in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, components

Imagine a situation where a certain component returns:

```
<Component1>
  <Component2 name="It's my name"/>
</Component1>
```

now, what I would like to achieve is something like this

```
<Component1 some_property={getComponent2'sName} //which evaluates to It's my name >
  <Component2 name="It's my name"/>
<Component1>
```

is this possible? If so, how?

For the context: both of these components are from (different) external packages, I'm not giving a specific example as the code is too messy in here and would only cause an unneeded headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a context, using React.createContext(), React.useContext and reducer, you can, you can see an example in this file: [context sample](https://gist.github.com/SitoNumbis/26746957503d0f77418fdcded0b4b241)

Where I defined 3 actions for the reducer, add to add a component to your set of components, remove to remove a component in a position and clean to clean your set.
How can you use this context?
First put the context in the code where you want to use it

```
<YourContextName>
  {Your react code}
</YourContextName>
```

How to call it?
Use the hook useYourContextName() to define your state variables inside the parent component

```
const { yourContextNameState, setYourContextNameState } = useYourContextName();
```

Then you can use yourContextNameState to access to your component attributes

```
<Component1 some_property={yourContextNameState.components[0].Name}>
  <Component2 name={yourContextNameState.components[0].Name}></Component2>
</Component1>
```

Whenever you want to add a component use:

```
setYourContextNameState({type: "add", newComponent: {your object}});
```

Don't worry it's look like a big and hard code, but is super easy, just you can reused the code everywhere you want

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this would be to store the string "It's my name" in a variable in the component that renders Components1 and Components2.
Maybe something like this - ask if there is any confusion.

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [name, setname] = useState("This is my name");

  return (
    <Component1 some_property={name}>
      <Component2 name={name}></Component2>
    </Component1>
  );
}
```

Comment: the name example is just a, well, example. It could be any other property - though name is what I need. Thought there could be a universal solution to this. What I'm trying to achieve is to prepare an object with several keys and its' values equal to the name of this nested Component (because there's more than just two components). And I don't want to hardcode this as this section is expected to grow.